trying to overwrite '/file', which is also in package foo
I have 2 custom Debian packages, dmsystem-facility and dmsystem-dev. Most of the time, the facility package will be installed without conflict, but if the dev package is installed I want it to use most of dmsystem-facility.deb's configuration files (dev depends on facility)  but I want dev to override facility's /etc/powerdns/pdns.conf file. Now I understand that the right way to do this is to use the debian/displace file in my configuration, but after reading the documentation and trying every variation of the file I can think of (with and without the .dmsystem ending on all absolute paths) I still get this error. What am I doing wrong?
